# Conways Game of Life trouble [java]

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

```
public static boolean[][] calculate(boolean cellState[][])//imports cell patern(in the form of a graph)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int alive = 0;
    boolean newCellState[][] = new boolean[50][50];//what the next generation is stored in

    while(x < 50 && y < 50)//calculation loop
    {
        try//each adjacent cell
        {
            if(cellState[x-1][y] == true)
                alive++; //if the  adjacent cell is alive the alive variable gets + 1
        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

        try
        {
            if (cellState[x-1][y-1] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        try
        {
            if(cellState[x-1][y+1] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        try
        {
            if (cellState[x][y+1] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        try
        {
            if (cellState[x][y-1] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        try
        {
            if(cellState[x+1][y] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        try
        {
            if(cellState[x+1][y-1] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        try
        {
            if(cellState[x+1][y+1] == true)
                alive++;
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { }

        if(cellState[x][y] = true) //determines if the cell should be alive in the next generation
        {
            if(alive < 2)
                newCellState[x][y] = false;
            else if(alive > 3)
                newCellState[x][y] = false;
            else if(alive == 2)
                newCellState[x][y] = true;//stores in new cell state for next gen
            else
                newCellState[x][y] = true;
        } else
        {
            newCellState[x][y] = false;
        }

        alive = 0; //resets alive

        if(x == 49)//counter for graph
        {
            y++;
            x=0;
        }else
        {
            x++;
        }
    }

    return newCellState;
}
```

This is my method that is used to calculate the next generation of Conway's game of life. Each time it is run, no matter what the pattern is, it prints out every cell as dead except the edges of the grid.

This is the main method:

```
public static void main(String Args[])
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    boolean cellState[][] = new boolean[50][50];
    String answer;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("\n Type anything for next generation, 'new' for new grid, or 'stop' to end>> ");
        answer = input.nextLine();
        if(answer.equals("new"))
        {
            cellState = newCells();
        }else if(answer.equals("stop"))
        {
            break;
        }else
        {
            cellState = calculate(cellState);
            print(cellState);
        }

    }


}
```

I have tested the printing method so it doesn't have a problem there. I just can't figure out why it does this. All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The `=` operator does __not__ test for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(cellState[x][y] = true)
```

You forgot to use  `==` for this one. Otherwise, your code looks fine.

Comment: The = was changed to == buy the problem still happens

Comment: Please update your post to account for the ==. I'm seeing that you changed all of them to == except the one that I specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` for testing and not `=` .

= will not serve your purpose in if conditions.

Comment: Oh my god how did I not see that! Thank you so much! Problem persists though.